# Not able to create DOM element using javascript factory pattern

Tags: javascript

I am trying to create html button using java-script factory pattern. 
This is the factory interface:

```
var _button = function(){};
_button.prototype.createButtonType = function(options){
    var buttonType = null;
    if(options.edit == true){
        buttonType = _edit;
    }
    else if(options.remove == true){
        buttonType = _remove;
    }
    return new buttonType(options.holder);
}

**The _edit & _remove functions are as follows**

var _edit = function(holder){
    console.log("Method executing : components._edit",holder)
    var buttonBasicEdit = _basicButton();

    buttonBasicEdit.className = "defaultEdit";  
    buttonBasicEdit.innerHTML = "Edit";
    buttonBasicEdit.onclick = function(){
        //someaction
    };

    holder.appendChild(buttonBasicEdit);    
}

var _remove = function(holder){
    console.log("Method executing : components._remove");
    var buttonBasicRemove = _basicButton();
    buttonBasicRemove.className = "defaultRemove";  
    holder.appendChild(buttonBasicRemove);      
};

function _basicButton(){
    console.log("Method Executing components._basicButton")
    var buttonBasic = document.createElement("button");
    return buttonBasic;
};

## The basic factory calling function is ##
var _buttons = new _button();
_buttons.createButtonType({
    edit:true,
    remove:true,
    holder:buttonHolder
});
```

The issue is when I am calling `if....else if` in prototype function it is only calling `_edit` function and creating edit button, simply overlooking the `_remove` function. But when using two consecutive `if` loop it throwns an `undefined is not a function` exception.

Comment: There is no function "buttonType".

Comment: Change `holder.appendchild(buttonBasicRemove);` to `holder.appendChild(buttonBasicRemove);`.

Comment: "buttonType" is basically varible. When I want to create an edit button I will set buttonType = _edit
So function will like this 
return new _edit(options.holder)
This is essence of factory pattern.

Comment: @dfsq that is a typo , I removed & checked it.Still it is only creating edit button

Comment: Are you trying to create two buttons or one button with two aspects?

Comment: I would suggest ensuring that `options.edit` is set and, by default, is set to `false`. You can do this at the beginning of the function with `options.edit = options.edit || false;` or something similar.

Comment: @LexR , I am trying to create two buttons, Edit & Remove.

Comment: Works good for me: http://jsfiddle.net/kd4e1zz3/ with the typo fixed.

Comment: @dfsq thanks for the fiddle , but can't it be possible to call prototype function only once like I wish to do and pass both edit & remove options, rather than calling it twice

Comment: @VaskarRayKarmakar If you know all of the states in advance then you could work through them in a loop, or you could use an array to pass multiple requests into the function at once. JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/eexhuj7w/2/